# .htaccess disables javascript for vue SPA app

Tags: vue.js, .htaccess, xampp

i have a Vue app that uses router and i have a route for (forgot my password) in form ../rp/:id like below

```
export const routes = [
  {
    path: '/rp/:id',
    name: 'resetPassword',
    component: resetPassword,
    props: true
  }
]

const router = new vueRouter({
  routes,
  mode: 'history'
});
```

i'm using nodejs as backend and i send the email but when i click on the email link to redirect me to resetPassword component i get

**We're sorry but the app doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.**

i'm using .htaccess written as follow:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /Restaurant
RewriteRule ^Restaurant/index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /Restaurant/index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

i don't know why it disable javascript

my index.html file contents are below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <noscript>
      <strong>We're sorry but the app doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.</strong>
    </noscript>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Restaurants</title>
  </head>
  <body style="height: 100vh">
    <div id="app"></div>
    <!-- built files will be auto injected -->
  </body>
</html>
```

can anyone help me with this? why it disable javascript?

thanks in advance

Comment: Most likely it is not your actual application logic that "disables" javascript. But instead your rewriting that breaks retrieving the javascript code from the server. You should check that in your browser console, look into the "network" tab in there and check for the separate requests. Any of those fail? What do you see?

Comment: it requests 3 js files and 1 css file with 200 status returned but in preview i see the same message above "We're sorry but the app doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue."

Comment: OK, thanks for checking, then it indeed looks like your server side logic is actively blocking here. Strange. Someone with experience in vue.js might no the next step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes! finally i got it to work,it was a very silly mistake that stopped me 2 days

it was vue router fault not htaccess /Restaurant/rp/:id not only /rp/:id

as follow:

```
export const routes = [
  {
    path: '/Restaurant/rp/:id',
    name: 'resetPassword',
    component: resetPassword,
    props: true
  }
]

const router = new vueRouter({
  routes,
  mode: 'history'
});
```

good luck everybody!